# UITableView long press to edit and single click to view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to display edit screen on long press of UITableView cell and display view screen on single click of UITableView cell in swift language?

```
@IBAction func editMethod(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            let cell = sender.view as! MyTableViewCell
            let editController = MyEditViewController()
            editController.sample= samples[cell.tag]
            presentViewController(editController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

I am using this code to display my edit controller but all the field outlets in MyEditViewController are nil because of this line 'let editController = MyEditViewController()'. Here I am creating new instance. So outlets are nil now. Is there any other way?

Comment: `LongPressGestureRecognizer`. Single tap is handled by default through `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: How can i get the selected cell number(indexpath) in the LongPressGestureRecognizer action method?

Comment: set tag of cell to indexPath.row in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate and by the sender of action method, get the view of sender. That will be the cell. Use its tag to know the indexPath.row.

Comment: Like this: `UITableViewCell *selectedCell = (UITableViewCell*)sender.view;` Now use selectedCell.tag for getting the indexPath.row

Comment: @NSNoob Please reply to my edited question